# Operatic vocals over modern beat from "Jacques Chirac: F Yeah!" You Tube video

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

Sad thing is that the song is in the background and the YouTuber speaks during the whole time so I can't manage to hear the words.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xHejLenKSs&t=143

It looks like a mix between classical music and sort of disco so maybe with just the classical title the whole music can be found.

Comment: It's a famous opera duet.  I know that much.

Comment: Yep, I heard it too once but can't put a name on it.

Comment: @PhillipSiebold - Your description of it as a famous duet definitely helped me find it!

Comment: @LHOOQ Great username, btw. :)

Comment: Hahaha! Thanks, it can sound sexist but you know, art ;-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a search for opera duets for two sopranos, and your song literally came up first!  This is the [*Flower Duet*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vf42IP__ipw) from *Lakmé*.

> The "Flower Duet" is a famous duet for sopranos from Léo Delibes' opera *Lakmé,* first performed in Paris in 1883. The duet takes place in act 1 of the three-act opera, between characters Lakmé, the daughter of a Brahmin priest, and her servant Mallika, as they go to gather flowers by a river.
>
> The duet is frequently used in advertisements and films and is popular as a concert piece.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flower_Duet

There seem to be many remixes of it.  This particular one seems like a plausible match: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oE8cKHuP0bI